# Найти значения в скобках и составить из них массив

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

```java
String text = "(слива) какие-то другие слова [яблоко], еще слова {груша}.";
```

Нужно найти слова в скобках и составить из них массив.

Если я пишу:

```java
text = text.replaceAll("(\\(|\\[|\\{)(.*?)(\\)|\\]|\\})", "o0o0o0 $2 o1o1o1")
           .replaceAll("o1o1o1(.*?)o0o0o0","")
           .replaceAll("o1o1o1|o0o0o0","")
           .replaceAll("[^а-я]"," ")
           .replaceAll("\\s+"," ");

String[] fruits = text.split(" ");

// [ , слива, яблоко, груша]
```

Получается длинновато.

**Вопрос:** Как упростить выражение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще найти все совпадения с помощью первого регулярного выражения, `[(\\[{](.*?)[)\\]}]`, которое находит подстроки между `(` / `[` / `{` и `)` / `]` / `}`.

- `[(\\[{]` - `(`, `[` или `{`
- `(.*?)` - захватывающая подмаска №1 (значение будет в `matcher.group(1)`): любые 0+ символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно меньше
- `[)\\]}]` - `)`, `]`, `}`

[См. Java-демо](https://ideone.com/cCIz2V):

```java
String text = "(слива) какие-то другие слова [яблоко], еще слова {груша}.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(\\[{](.*?)[)\\]}]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    lst.add(matcher.group(1));
} 
System.out.println(lst); 
// => [слива, яблоко, груша]
```

Comment: Кстати, если в тексте внутри скобок не должно быть пробелов, замените `.*?` на `\\S*?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\([а-я]+\)|\[[а-я]+\]|\{[а-я]+\}
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/PVIXkR/1)

Эта регулярка проверялась для `javascript`, так что для `java` возможно потребуется добавить косых палок - но основную суть вы поняли, надеюсь.

ps. в джавке я не работал с регулярками, так что как это разбить на массив лучше - виднее Вам, поскольку не могу ручаться за методы работы с ними. Но упростить - вот одно выражение, ищущее все скобки. Не забудьте добавить в конце флаг `\g`

Comment: В регулярных выражениях Java отсутствует поддержка флага `g`, и поиск всех совпадений необходимо реализовывать с помощью кода на основе `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew сочувствую

Comment: А ещё ваше `[а-я]+` не найдёт буквы `ё`.